Is glub glub sound from kitchen sink serious?
For a few months, my kitchen sink has been making a glub glub sound when the dishwasher is draining.  The sound does not seem to come from any other sink on a higher or lower floor.
Is this serious or can I just not worry about it?
Related: Why is my kitchen island sink gurgling when my dishwasher is draining?
